# Taylor polynomials and composition

Tags: calculus

Why, when I develop, for instance, $f(x) = \sin(5x^{2}+3)$ at $0$ using function composition, do I have to take the polynomial of $sin$ around $3$ and not around $0$?

I don't understand this process.

Comment: Your series is around 3 if it contains powers of (x-3). If it contains series of x, it is around 0

Comment: I guess you are intersted in the MacLaurin series. To this end use $$\sin(5x^2+3)=\cos 3\sin(5x^2)+\sin 3\cos(5x^2)$$ and the MacLaurin series of $\sin$ and $\cos.$

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f$, a Taylor series for $f$ centered at $a$ has the form $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n.$$ This will converge for all $x$ in some interval of convergence $I$. Here, $f^{(n)}$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f$, and $f^{(n)}(a)$ is the value of the $n^{th}$ derivative at $a$.

Suppose we want a series for $\sin(5x^2+3)$ at $a=0$. Then we have to have a series of the form $$\sin(5x^2+3)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (x-0)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\tag{GOAL}$$ Here, I don't really care what the $c_n$ are yet. I'm focused on getting the $a=0$ part first.

Let's take a series for $\sin(x)$ centered at some $b$.  We have $$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}(x-b)^n.$$ Since $x$ is just the name of a variable, we can change to another variable name. Let's change to $u$. $$\sin(u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}(u-b)^n.$$  Since this converges on $I=(-\infty,\infty)$, we can plug in any $u$ we want, and we get a true equation. Plug in $u=5x^2+3$ to get $$\sin(5x^2+3)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}(5x^2+3-b)^n.$$  But, as stated above in the equation labeled **GOAL**, we want the non-constant part of the terms of our series to be $x^n$. How can we get $(5x^2+3-b)^n$ to be a constant multiple of $x^n$? The only way is to take $b=3$ to get the $3$s to cancel. Taking $b=3$, we get $$\sin(u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(3)}{n!}(u-3)^n,$$ $$\sin(5x^2+3)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(3)}{n!}(5x^2+3-3)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(3)}{n!}5^n x^{2n},$$ and we have reached **GOAL** with $c_{2n}=\frac{f^{(n)}(3)}{n!}5^n$, and $c_n=0$ for all odd $n$.

For concreteness, let's look at why we cannot use the $\sin(x)$ series centered at $b=0$ to get a series for $\sin(5x^2+3)$ centered at $a=0$. We have $$\sin(u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}u^n,$$ $$\sin(5x^2+3)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(5x^2+3)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} 5^n (x^2-(-3/5))^n.\tag{OOPS}$$  The equation labeled **OOPS** is $100\%$, absolutely a true statement. The problem with this series isn't that it's not valid. The problem is that it's not a Taylor series, because Taylor series have to have a constant $c_n$ times an expression of the form $(x-a)^n$, not $(x^2-a)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to compute Taylor expansion of sine at $3$, since the argument $x^2+3$ tends to $3$ as $x\to0$.

Let's see at order $3$:

$$\sin(t)=\sin(3)+\cos(3)(t-3)-\frac{\sin(3)}2(t-3)^2+O((t-3)^3)$$

Plug $t=5x^2+3$ and you get:

$$\sin(5x^2+3)=\sin(3)+5^2\cos(3)x^2-\frac{5^4\sin(3)}2x^4+O(x^6)$$

This works as well if $5x^2+3$ is replaced with a Taylor approximation, you will just have to take care about the orders you need to keep in the computation.

For instance, with $\sin(3+5x^2+O(x^3))$, you would get

$$\sin(3+5x^2+O(x^3))=\sin(3)+\cos(3)(5x^2+O(x^3))-\frac{\sin(3)}2(5x^2+O(x^3))^2\\
=\sin(3)+5^2\cos(3)x^2+O(x^3)$$

Comment: thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

We  can use the Taylor series of $\sin t$ at $t=3,$ and plug in $t=5x^2+3.$ Alternatively for this particular example we can use trigonometry $$\sin(5x^2+3)=\cos 3\sin(5x^2)+\sin 3\cos(5x^2)\\=
\cos 3\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^{n+1}5^{2n+1}\over (2n+1)!}x^{4n+2}\\ +\sin3\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n5^{2n}\over (2n)!}x^{4n}$$ which gives the MacLaurin series of $\sin(5x^2+3).$